# Could IPv4 loopback addresses be used for IPC?

Tags: network-programming, ip, ipc, loopback, ipv4

I was quite surprised when I found out that there was a really big range of IP addresses allocated for loopback (127.x.y.z).

I didn't find much information about why it's like this, except that it could be used for testing networks and protocols locally, which got me thinking if it could be a good idea to use these addresses for IPC.

At the moment, as far as I know, IPC based on networking is usually done with TCP/UDP by opening sockets on ports which are most likely not used by any other service.

So my question is, to be even more sure that there won't be a port collision, could other loopback addresses be used instead?

For a more concrete example, could two processes communicate through sockets on address 127.31.41.59 and ports 27 and 18 (or even different loopback addresses)?